# How do you change a value in a CSV file through python?

Tags: python, csv

I need to be able to find and change a value in a CSV stock file. I know how to search for a value but when I try to use the `csv.writer` then it returns an error.

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "\\pbsrvfile\ExamAccounts$\ITCA76\ochot_krystian_a453\Task 3\Task 3.pyw", line 8, in <module>
    for row in writer:
TypeError: '_csv.writer' object is not iterable
```

I have no idea why it is doing that. So far I have this for the code:

```
import csv
code=input('Enter code to search: ')
stock=open ('Stock Levels.csv', 'wb')
writer=csv.writer(stock)
for row in writer:
    for field in row:
        if field==code:
            print('Record found! \n')
            print('Code: '+row[0])
            print('Product name: '+row[1])
            print('Target level: '+row[2])
            target = int(row[2])
            print('Current level: '+row[3]+'\n')
            current = int(row[3])
            restock_amount = target - current
            restocked_value = restock_amount + current
            writer.writerow[3](restocked_value)
            print(row[1]+' has been restocked to '+restocked_value)
```

Can anyone tell me how to fix the error or if there is another way to modify the value. I am using python 3.2.3

Comment: If there is anything wrong with my question please just tell me.

Comment: I don't understand what you attempt to iterate over in the *for row in writer* line. Surely it can't be the empty CSV file you just opened, shouldn't it be some sort of input?

Comment: That part of the code is used for searching for the correct row

Comment: The file that I was trying to open was the file that had the data I wanted to modify.

Comment: Problem: opening a file with *w* instead of *a* truncates it to zero bytes.

Comment: I did find that 1 in 3 times that I ran the module it lost all of its data. Fortunately I had a backup.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Try this:

```
import csv
import os
code=input('Enter code to search: ')
with open ('Stock Levels.csv', 'r') as stock:
    reader=csv.reader(stock, delimiter=',')

    with open ('New Stock Levels.csv', 'w') as newStock:
        writer=csv.writer(newStock, delimiter=',')
        for row in reader:
            if code in row:
                print('Record found! \n')
                print('Code: '+row[0])
                print('Product name: '+row[1])
                print('Target level: '+row[2])
                target = int(row[2])
                print('Current level: '+row[3]+'\n')
                current = int(row[3])
                restock_amount = target - current
                restocked_value = restock_amount + current
                row[3] = restocked_value
                print(row[1]+' has been restocked to '+str(restocked_value))
            writer.writerow(row)
os.remove('Stock Levels.csv')
os.rename('New Stock Levels.csv', 'Stock Levels.csv')
```

If you use `with open` instead of `open` you don't have to close the file.

The code works like this:

- Read stock levels (you might have to change the delimiter to whatever
  you have)
- Look at each line in stock levels and modify it if you see
  your code to search
- Write ALL lines of stock levels back to new stock
  levels, including the modified lines
- Delete the old file to enable the `New Stock Levels.csv` file to be renamed to the older version (make sure you have a backup)
- Rename `New Stock Levels.csv` to `Stock Levels.csv`

I don't think you can modify a file directly, I think you always have to read it, modify, write to temp file and then rename.

Comment: If the file is very big, you can also copy it to the temp file one line at a time.

Comment: I think it all works fine until the point where it tries to rename the new file. It returns an error that it cannot create a file when that file already exists.

Comment: your script must have permission to overwrite the file, perhaps it can only create files

Comment: The error was that python could not rename the new file while the old one existed, I found a solution to this and edited your answer to contain this information. Thanks for your help.